# Trying to obtain a voltage gain equal to 3 without an op-amp

Tags: amplifier, wien-bridge

I'm a beginner in electronics and currently, I am trying to design a Wien bridge oscillator. I've read documents about oscillators. For now I am stuck at trying to design the amplifier, without using op-amps. I'm trying to obtain a voltage gain equal to 3, to respect the Barkhausen condition.

Can you give me some ideas or advice about what I'm doing wrong? The Wien Bridge is disconnected so that I can verify the gain of the amplifier.

[image: schematic]

[image: output voltage]

Comment: Perhaps you'd briefly describe what you think each piece of your amplifier is doing. It looks like you've simply copied the design of an opamp. There are far easier ways to make an amplifier with a gain of 3, with a single transistor or two.

Comment: The gain must be somewhat larger than 3 - because of a safe start of oscillation and you need some "room" for amplitude control.

Comment: The differential pair and the transistors q16 and q17 are my amplifier stage. I`m pretty sure I have messed up the bias of q16 and q17. R18 and R13 are my Negative Feedback Loop, Q8 is R15 U1 C3 and R31 are my attempt at an automatic Gain Control. I have used Q11 as a current source for the dif-amp and biased it with R6 R20 and D1. Hope this was explicit enough.

Comment: The gain of Q17 is reduced by the 4 loads it drives. Then it needs an open-loop gain that is much higher than 3. A real opamp has an output that has such a low output impedance that a load does not reduce its output level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your amplifier inputs the wrong way around.

This design below uses a conventional voltage amplifier stage (Q6 & Q11) with its current source load (Q9).

I've also added an output stage to drive a load.

R13 & R14 linearise the J-fet.

[image: Wien Oscillator]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A darlington bipolar, to have high input resistance so your Wein circuit remains on frequency, with 1Kohm in  the emitter and 3K ohm in the collector, will provide approximately 3X gain.

Then follow that with an emitter follower to handle some loads.

You will need to "adjust the gain", likely in real time with an Automatic Level Control.